# LibreOffice base table lookup

Tags: libreoffice, database

I am recently transitioning from MS Access to LibreOffice base.

I am trying to create a new DB with table lookups. I have searched google, YouTube and stack exchange but I think I don't know the right keywords for my search. Instead of trying to describe the problem I will instead use an example from MS Access.

In Access you create table one. Then create table two and one of the fields is of type lookup. That then asks what table and field will be the info in the field in table 2. When entering data in the table, that field will have a combo-box that will let you select the records from table 1. In SQL this can only be done in a query using inner joins.

I could do that in this DB but I would hope this feature is available in table design. I don't like to create queries and forms before all of the tables are complete. Is there a way to do this in table design mode? or will it have to be done with queries?

Comment: To understand the question, I looked at https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239.  Hopefully that describes what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LO table data view mode does not have such complex features.

Instead, create a form for table two with a combo box.  Specify *Sql* list contents and write a query to select data from table one.

Or, in the form, use a table control for table two.  Then *Insert Column -> Combo Box*.  This way it looks and feels like table data view mode.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm sad that this is not a feature. Thank you and have a nice day.